# Getting a cancelled javascript prompt to do nothing

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a page with frames.  The upper frame is a header that contains controls to perform searches against a database, the lower is used to display the search results.
The user can click on a search mode button, get a prompt where they enter the search criteria, and then view the results in the lower frame.

Everything works great except when the user cancels the prompt.  The page reloads and puts the upper (header) html into the lower frame.

The code for one of the search modes:

```
        function searchBySid(){
            var sidNum = prompt("Enter the SID to search for:","");
            if(sidNum!=null){
                document.getElementById("formType").value = "SearchBySid";
                document.getElementById("sid").value = sidNum;
                var form = document.getElementById("headerForm");
                form.action="OffenderRegistration";
                form.method="GET";
                form.submit();
            }
        }
```

How do I get the page to do NOTHING if the prompt is cancelled?

EDIT:

It's called by a button onclick:

```
            <table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td><button id="btnSearchSid" name="btnSearchSid" class="menuButton" onclick="searchBySid()">Search by SID</button></td>
                    <td><button id="btnSearchDps" name="btnSearchDps" class="menuButton" onclick="searchByDps()">Search by DPS</button></td>
                    <td><button id="btnSearchName" name="btnSearchName" class="menuButton" onclick="searchByName()">Search by Name</button></td>
                    <td><button id="btnAdd" name="btnAdd" class="menuButton" onclick="getAddForm()">Add</button></td>
                    <td><button id="btnReports" name="btnReports" class="menuButton">Reports</button></td>
                    <td style="color: white;">&nbsp;Today's Date:&nbsp;<label style="color: white;" id="lblDate"></label></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: How are you calling the function! You probably need to cancel that action!

Comment: How are you calling `searchBySid`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not show how you are calling the function, but it sounds like you are not cancelling some sort of click action

```
onclick="searchBySid();return false;"
```

It would be better to do it with [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Comment: `event.preventDefault` is sufficient.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen If the browser supports it.

Comment: Which one doesn't? IE5?

Comment: More like Internet Explorer 8.

Comment: Frits:  event.preventDefault didn't seem to work.  'Course I'm not quite sure where it's supposed to go, either.  However, epascarello's answer seems to work.

Comment: @BobStout preventDefault would work if you passed in the event object as long as the browser supports it. `function searchBySid(e) { e = e || window.event; e.preventDefault();`